# Binding a member signal to a function

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-bind, boost-signals

This line of code compiles correctly without a problem:

```
boost::bind(boost::ref(connected_),
            boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<session<version> >(shared_from_this()),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error);
```

However when assigning it to a *boost::function* or as a callback like this:

```
socket_->async_connect(connection_->remote_endpoint(),
                      boost::bind(boost::ref(connected_),
                      boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<session<version> >(shared_from_this()),
                      boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

I'm getting a whole bunch of [incomprehensible errors](http://pastie.org/966969) (linked since it's too long to fit here).

On the other hand I have succeeded binding a free signal to a boost::function like this:

```
void print(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    cout << "session connected";
}

int main()
{
boost::signal<void(const boost::system::error_code &)> connected_;
connected_.connect(boost::bind(&print, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    client<>::connection_t::socket_ptr socket_(new client<>::connection_t::socket_t(conn->service())); // shared_ptr of a tcp socket

    socket_->async_connect(conn->remote_endpoint(),
                       boost::bind(boost::ref(connected_),
                       boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    conn->service().run(); // io_service.run()
    return 0;
}
```

This works and prints `session connected` correctly.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through the bind [troubleshooting guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_signature)? I'm not familiar with your compiler, but your error seems similar to the second bullet in the troubleshooting section "The function object cannot be called with the specified arguments."